# -Os flag necessary to make general purpose register behave normally

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I am currently working with a TI EK-LM4F120XL board. This board contains a Cortex-M4F cpu. I am using the following chain:

ARM GCC None EABI
https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.8/4.8-2014-q2-update

And the following debugger:

OpenOCD http://openocd.sourceforge.net/

The problem is that I need to use the -Os flag to prevent strange behaviour. An example, using code provided by TI:

Default linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM

    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM
}
```

The startup_gcc.c file: [pastbin, because the file is large](http://pastebin.com/AY2CvdNh)

And a very simple blinker:

```
int
main(void)
{
    volatile unsigned long ulLoop;

    //
    // Enable the GPIO port that is used for the on-board LED.
    //
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R = SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOF;

    //
    // Do a dummy read to insert a few cycles after enabling the peripheral.
    //
    ulLoop = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;

    //
    // Enable the GPIO pin for the LED (PF3).  Set the direction as output, and
    // enable the GPIO pin for digital function.
    //
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x08;
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x08;

    //
    // Loop forever.
    //
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Turn on the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R |= 0x08;

        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        for(ulLoop = 0; ulLoop < 200000; ulLoop++)
        {
        }

        //
        // Turn off the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R &= ~(0x08);

        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        for(ulLoop = 0; ulLoop < 200000; ulLoop++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing special, all default code as created by TI. Compilation and linking commands:

```
~/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc blink.c startup_gcc.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_LM4F120H5QR -c -I/home/jacko/git/jackoOS/stellaris-exe  -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
~/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld -T blink.ld --entry ResetISR -o a.out startup_gcc.o blink.o --gc-sections
```

As you can see the compiling command contains a -Os param. If I add this to the command everything works fine, but if I remove it, register 7 starts to act very weird:

```
(gdb) monitor reg
===== arm v7m registers
(0) r0 (/32): 0x00000000
...
(7) r7 (/32): 0x200000F0
...
(13) sp (/32): 0x200000F0
...
(17) msp (/32): 0x200000F0
...
===== Cortex-M DWT registers
...
(36) dwt_3_function (/32)
(gdb) cont
...
(gdb) monitor reg
===== arm v7m registers
...
(7) r7 (/32): 0x200000E0
...
(13) sp (/32): 0x200000E0
...
(17) msp (/32): 0x200000E0
(18) psp (/32): 0x00000000
...
===== Cortex-M DWT registers
...
(36) dwt_3_function (/32)
```

(full dump can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/P55h4BRN))

R7 has the same value as the SP (MSP = active SP)! Why would it do that?

If I try to write to R7 with:

```
MOV     R7, R0
```

The program just crashes into a hard fault.

So, why is this -Os flag so important? Why does R7 act so weird without it?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Why is `r7` so important? I can't see anything that explicitly uses `r7`.

Comment: R7 is a general purpose cpu register and should behave as such. The cpu regs are always used implicitly by the compiled code.

Comment: So? As far as I can see, that's what's happening here.

Comment: You've found a "problem" (gcc is using register to do something), and you're looking for a solution... Please... First give us a reason why gcc couldn't store whatever it wants - like a copy of SP (frame pointer [FP] as noted in the answer below) - wherever it wants - like in r7.

Comment: Well that was condesending. I had a register that was not behaving according to the datasheet and the question why. I was not suggesting that it was the fault of GCC, I just noted that I needed an optimalization flag to make a GP-reg behave like one, which I found strange.

Comment: The hardware doesn't define the ABI - "general-purpose" defines its use by _hardware_ i.e. there are no restrictions on using it as a source/destination/base register in instruction encodings. What _software_ may do with it is then entirely down to the compiler and whatever ABI it follows.

Comment: Where / how do you alter R7?

Comment: In another function, while context switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC uses R7 as FP under thumb mode. Try "-fomit-frame-pointer" if you are not using any optimization flag to avoid that behavior.

Comment: It is also worth thinking about the _reason_ to prevent this behavior, because it's there on purpose... Disabling it just for the sake of r7 behaving "normally" is not such a good idea...

Comment: Thank you! One more question: how do you explain that setting the R7 leads to a hard fault?

Comment: @Cheiron um, because _it's the [frame pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#FRAME-POINTER)_. When you try accessing local variables at offsets from something that now doesn't even point at RAM, let alone the stack, how well do you think that's going to go?

Comment: @FreddieChopin Afaik purpose is just for debugging or back-tracing? I didn't get how OP is altering R7, if it was inline assembly he probably should have 'clobbered' it.

Comment: While this is a good start to say it is a *stack* issue, I don't think the `fp` itself will cause issue, unless GCC is buggy. For instance, `(void (*)(void))((unsigned long)pulStack + sizeof(pulStack))` could be `(void (*)(void))((unsigned long)pulStack + sizeof(pulStack)) - 1` for a full-descending stack.  The `-O2` and `-O3` options will generally use more stack space.  `-Os` never inlines and always pops stack frames.

Comment: I was altering r7 because I was writing a context switcher. I wanted to push R7 to a place in the RAM and load it again from another place.